# Does D3 have a "link analysis" type graph?

Tags: html, d3.js, interactive, data-representation

I'm looking for a link analysis-type tree representation, where the nodes can be arbitrarily linked to other multiple nodes, and the visual representation (grouping, formatting) of those nodes can be controlled (google images for "Analyst's Notebook" for excellent examples of these kinds of link-node layouts.  This would be for very large network analysis.

Here's one example (content not my use case).  Note how a node might be connected to multiple nodes.

[image]

Comment: I believe in d3 these are referred to as "force-directed graphs"

Comment: I've added an image of the kind of graph I'm referring to.  Do you still think a D3 force-directed graph" could handle that?